# Calculating position variations

Tags: mysql

MySql newbie here. I will try my best to explain my problem. I have the following records on a table:

```
Date       | Course                     | Position
-------------------------------------------------     
2017-02-28 | Portuguese Language Course | 24
2017-03-02 | Portuguese Language Course | 23
2017-03-04 | Portuguese Language Course | 24
2017-03-08 | Portuguese Language Course | 26
```

and I am struggling with a query to get the following:

```
Date       | Course                     | Position | Variation
---------------------------------------------------|----------     
2017-03-08 | Portuguese Language Course | 26       | +2
2017-03-04 | Portuguese Language Course | 24       | +1
2017-03-02 | Portuguese Language Course | 23       | -1
2017-02-28 | Portuguese Language Course | 24       | 0
```

In short I want to get for each date in descending order the variation for the column position.

Any idea how I should approach this?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Luis

Comment: how is the variation calculated? why is 2017-03-04 +1 and not 0?

Comment: @davejal I think it is (from top to bottom) 26-24 (+2), 24-23 (+1), 23-24 (-1), 24-\0 (0) `\0` as empty

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subquery.

```
SELECT t.*, t.position - t2.position as variation
FROM courses t, courses t2
WHERE t2.course = t.course
  AND t2.date = COALESCE((SELECT MAX(t3.date)
                 FROM courses t3
                 WHERE t3.course = t.course
                 AND t3.date < t.date), t.date)
ORDER BY t.date DESC
```

This will join the table with itself on a 1 row to 1 row basis.
For each row in t, we pair it with a single row in t2, which is the newest row before t.date.

To do this we have to get the max date, we do that in a subquery. But that subquery can't tell us which position is associated with that date, so we match it outside the subquery using t2.

And finally, there's the case where there are no earlier dates. For that, we just use the record where t2.date = t.date. COALESCE will use the second argument when the first one is null, so it's handy here.

Comment: Can you be guaranteed the subquery is filtering the same course as the outside query?

Comment: @Ilion if I fix the typo of `1` to `t` doesn't that do it?

Comment: Apparently it does! I wasn't aware you could reference external queries like that. Cool! Found this for more reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery

Comment: using your query I couldn't get the last row ... http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/906c58/7/0 (only 3 rows, where the result should be 4 rows)

Comment: @davejal I mentioned in the last sentence that it's not complete. But I'm home with more time now so I finished it.

Comment: Although this work fine for the OP dataset, if you add one more row say `2017-03-04 | Portuguese Language Course | 22` it will break. Though the OP should say something about this specific requirement (same date for two rows)

Comment: @JorgeCampos I wouldn't necessarily call it broken. There would be no way to order the two orders that came in on the same day, so placing either one first wouldn't matter. We could also assume that the table is keyed on (date, course)

Comment: I said that it breaks not because of the ordering reason (I agree with you here), I mentioned that in my comment, but because it duplicates a row in the result set. See it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a107f/1 see the line of `march, 08`

Comment: @JorgeCampos I thought the duplicates wouldn't be a problem. But I see what you mean, the day after duplicates entries will also have a duplicate result. That is problematic. Hopefully his schema solves it

Comment: Thanks Guys, this one nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

You could select the beginning value in a subquery and calculate the rest using the selected referenced value.

```
select date, course, c.position,c.position-a.position variation from courses c, (select position from courses order by date asc limit 1) a
```

Here an [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/906c58/5/0)